# Flutter fix not givving suggestions for quick fix deprecated methods/parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

According to the documentation on the new Flutter 2
(https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/flutter-fix), whenever a deprecated function is detected it should present an error and a quick fix.
I got the errors, but the quick fix isn't show, only the option to ignore hint.
I'm using vscode, already tryed to use vscode insiders, switch to flutter channel dev (Flutter 2.1), android studio is the same...
Also, when I run "dart fix --dry-run" no warnings are shown:

Computing fixes in project_test (dry run)...
Nothing to fix!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`flutter fix` is still an early experiment, and can only "fix" things for which it has a before/after mapping for analyzer-reported issues.  It will very likely get better over time.  Be sure you search the issues list and star any similar issues, or write one of your own so the team knows it's important.

Comment: But I was trying the same example they have... when they type the overflow parameter in the Stack Widget, acording to the official documentation should get an quick fix to "Migrate to 'clipBehavior'"
I was expecting the same thing in my IDE

Comment: I don't believe the transformations in `dart fix` are available as "quick fixes" in the IDE.

Comment: According to the official documentation yes...
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/flutter-fix

Comment: It's not like this is a major issue, I can do the changes on my own. it just would help a lot migrating some old projects.
I thought that it was just a problem of my enviroment, that's why I made the question

Comment: Yeah, I get now.  Thanks.  Certainly, star or create an issue if it's reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a weird issue with dart analyser.
In this particular case only happens if overflow is the only argument and there is a trailing comma.
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45242
I couldn't make it work with other deprecated objects like FlatButton and RaisedButton,
but as Randal Schwartz said flutter fix is still an early experiment